# DiscordAPIError[0]: 401: Unauthorized

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

When I try to run the command on the powershell termianl (node .\index.js\) I get the same error every time. I changed the token multiple times but still got the same error. I run the command on the right root directory, so I don't know what to do.

**Code:**

```
import { config } from 'dotenv';
import { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Routes } from 'discord.js';
import { REST } from '@discordjs/rest';

config();

const TOKEN = process.env.BOT_TOKEN_CLOUD;
const CLIENT_ID = process.env.CLIENT_ID;
const GUILD_ID = process.env.GUILD_ID;

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
    ]
});

const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken('TOKEN');

client.on('ready', () => {console.log(`${client.user.tag} has logged in!`);});

async function main() {
    const commands = [
        {
            name: 'testcommand',
            description: 'test command'
        },
    ];
    try {
        console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.');
        await rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(CLIENT_ID, GUILD_ID), {
            body: commands,
        });
        client.login(TOKEN);
    }   catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

main();
```

**Error:**

```
DiscordAPIError[0]: 401: Unauthorized
at SequentialHandler.runRequest (file:///C:/Users/Name/Documents/djs-v14/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/lib/handlers/SequentialHandler.mjs:283:15)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (file:///C:/Users/Name/Documents/djs-v14/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/lib/handlers/SequentialHandler.mjs:95:14)
at async REST.request (file:///C:/Users/Name/Documents/djs-v14/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/lib/REST.mjs:48:22)
at async main (file:///C:/Users/Name/Documents/djs-v14/index.js:32:9) {
rawError: { message: '401: Unauthorized', code: 0 },
  code: 0,
  status: 401,
  method: 'PUT',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/applications/CLIENT_ID/guilds/948742790421053482/commands',
  requestBody: { files: undefined, json: [ [Object] ] }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the specific token for your bot instead of 'TOKEN' string

const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken('TOKEN');
here, .setToken() should be like .setToken(TOKEN)

Answer (score 1):

Almost certain you forgot the ApplicationCommands scope(remember bot as well) when adding a bot to the server. Ensure you add that scope in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers). Another possible reason is your client ID not matching the token.

[image: Scopes in portal]